# SwiftUI - Enable Text view to present trailing whitespace

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, textview, uitextview

I have a a Text("string") view in SwiftUI that displays two different strings, one much longer than the other. I would like my SwiftUI text view to present both strings as if they were equal in length, so the view remains the same size (I have other dynamic elements on the page that I do not want it affecting).

To handle this, I am padding my shorter string with spaces (" ") until it reaches the length of the larger string. This does not solve my issue - it seems like SwiftUI Text view is ignoring the trailing whitespace and not presenting it on the screen. Is there any way to resolve this?

Comment: Add a minimum reproducible example

Answer (score 0):

If you are OK with having the texts occupying the whole width of the parent view, or if you can use `.frame(width:)` to have a fixed width, you could try the following approach:

```
        VStack {
            HStack {
                Text("Short")
                Spacer()
            }
            .background(.blue)
            
            HStack {
                Text("A very, very long text to show")
                Spacer()
            }
            .background(.yellow)
        }
        .padding()
```

You'll see that the blue and yellow areas are the same size.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `ZStack` and hidden copies of both texts to establish the space needed:

```swift
private var text1: Text {
    Text("A short string")
}

private var text2: Text {
    Text("A much longer string")
}

var body: some View {
    VStack(spacing: 30) {
        ZStack(alignment: .leading) {
            text1.hidden()
            text2.hidden()
            text1
        }
        .border(.orange)

        ZStack(alignment: .leading) {
            text1.hidden()
            text2.hidden()
            text2
        }
        .border(.orange)
    }
}
```

[image: EqualLengthTexts]